# How to set the local dictionary in a *Org Note* buffer?

Tags: org-mode, flyspell

I am using different flyspell/ispell dictionaries for different buffers/files setting the file local variable `ispell-local-dictionary`, respectively.

But if I want to log e.g. a TODO state change a `*Org Note*` buffer is opened with `org mode`as its major mode, as expected. Is there a way to tell Emacs to change the dictionary for every `*Org Note*` buffer to a specific language?

I did not find a specific `hook`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the `org-log-buffer-setup-hook` hook which is run after the log buffer is created. Here's a function that jumps to the other window, collects the language and sets it in the log buffer.

```
(add-hook 'org-log-buffer-setup-hook
      (lambda ()
        (let (dict)
          (other-window 1 nil)
          (setq dict ispell-local-dictionary)
          (other-window 1 nil)
          (ispell-change-dictionary dict))))
```